# Combine multiple dataframes by taking the average of rows with duplicated rownames and merge with unique rows

Tags: r

I have three data frames `methylresolver.output`, `EPICdeconv.output`, and `methylcibersort.output`. The output data frame is `meth_deconv`.

First, subset the data frames based on common column names.

For the rows, there are two possible scenarios:
(1) If the row name is common between two or more of these data frames, take the average/mean of these rows and return it as a single row in `meth_deconv`.
(2) However, if the row name is unique, meaning found in only one data frame and not the others, append these rows as-is to `meth_deconv`

The `meth_deconv` output should have unique row names and column names. There is no need for rounding up to significant figures. NOTE: The expected output below is just an estimate.

My code returned duplicated row names.

Code:

```
# Step 1: Retain only common column names
common_columns <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list(methylcibersort.output, methylresolver.output, EPICdeconv.output), colnames))

# Step 2: Calculate average for common rows
intersect_multiple <- function(list_of_sets) {
  if (length(list_of_sets) == 0) {
    return(character(0))
  } else if (length(list_of_sets) == 1) {
    return(list_of_sets[[1]])
  } else {
    return(Reduce(intersect, list_of_sets))
  }
}

# Calculate common rows using the custom function
common_rows <- intersect_multiple(list(rownames(methylcibersort.output), rownames(methylresolver.output), rownames(EPICdeconv.output)))
df_common <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(common_rows), ncol = length(common_columns)))
colnames(df_common) <- common_columns
df_common$Row <- common_rows
rownames(df_common) <- common_rows  # Set row names

# Calculate unique rows using Reduce
unique_rows <- Reduce(function(x, y) union(x, setdiff(y, x)), 
                      list(rownames(methylcibersort.output), 
                           rownames(methylresolver.output), 
                           rownames(EPICdeconv.output)))
df_unique <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = length(common_columns)))
colnames(df_unique) <- common_columns

# Populate df_common
df_common <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = length(common_columns) + 1))
colnames(df_common) <- c(common_columns, "Row")
df_common$Row <- character(0)

for (rowname in common_rows) {
  rows <- c(rownames(methylcibersort.output) %in% rowname,
            rownames(methylresolver.output) %in% rowname,
            rownames(EPICdeconv.output) %in% rowname)
  
  if (sum(rows) >= 2) {
    avg_values <- colMeans(rbind(methylcibersort.output[rowname, common_columns],
                                 methylresolver.output[rowname, common_columns],
                                 EPICdeconv.output[rowname, common_columns]), na.rm = TRUE)
    
    df_common <- rbind(df_common, c(avg_values, Row = rowname))
    rownames(df_common) <- df_common$Row
  }
}


# Populate df_unique
df_unique <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = length(common_columns)))
colnames(df_unique) <- common_columns
df_unique$Row <- character(0)

for (data in list(methylresolver.output, EPICdeconv.output, methylcibersort.output)) {
  unique_to_data <- setdiff(rownames(data), common_rows)
  df_data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique_to_data), ncol = length(common_columns)))
  colnames(df_data) <- common_columns
  df_data$Row <- unique_to_data
  
  for (i in seq_along(unique_to_data)) {
    row <- unique_to_data[i]
    values <- ifelse(common_columns %in% colnames(data), data[row, common_columns], NA)
    df_data[i, 1:(ncol(df_data)-1)] <- values
  }
  
  df_unique <- rbind(df_unique, df_data)
}

# Set row names for df_unique
rownames(df_unique) <- df_unique$Row
df_unique$Row <- NULL

# Combine common and unique rows
meth_deconv <- rbind(df_common, df_unique)

# Drop rows if NA or 0 in most rows
meth_deconv <- meth_deconv[rowSums(!is.na(meth_deconv[, -1])) >= 10, ]
meth_deconv <- meth_deconv[rowSums(meth_deconv[, -1] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) != ncol(df) - 1, ]

# Set row names as "Row" column
names <- meth_deconv$Row
meth_deconv$Row <- NULL
meth_deconv <- as.data.frame(meth_deconv)
rownames(meth_deconv) <- names
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘Dendritic’, ‘Fibro’, ‘Mon’, ‘Tmem’, ‘Tnaive’, ‘Treg’
```

Input:

```
> dput(methylcibersort.output[1:4,1:3])
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(0.0364182894497662, 0.138668938165071, 
0.124833542990477, 0.0532035320971197), TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(0.0723949608836049, 
0.121673792642051, 0.141351252071118, 0.0585041034979008), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(0.0889617571282722, 
0.0761483194555305, 0.119758779747065, 0.0197543005139569)), row.names = c("CD8", 
"Bcell", "Macro", "NK"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(methylresolver.output[1:3,1:3])
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(0, 0.0426955092785973), TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(0, 
0.0292977468566212), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(0, 0)), row.names = c("CD8", 
"Bcell"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(EPICdeconv.output[1:3,1:3])
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(0.0586, 0.2964, 8e-04), TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(0.0184, 
0.3026, 0), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(0.0158, 0.2933, 0)), row.names = c("CD8", 
"Bcell", "Macro"), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(0.0313, 0.2964, 0.1248, 0.053), TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(0.0454, 0.1512, 0.1414, 0.0585), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(0.0524, 0.1847, 0.1198, 0.01975)), row.names = c("CD8", "Bcell", "Macro", "NK"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tideverse` option could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = list(EPICdeconv.output, methylcibersort.output, methylresolver.output),
        ~ .x %>%
         rownames_to_column()) %>%
 group_by(rowname) %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
 ungroup()

  rowname TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 TCGA.Y8.A897.01
  <chr>             <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Bcell            0.159           0.151           0.123 
2 CD8              0.0317          0.0303          0.0349
3 Macro            0.0628          0.0707          0.0599
4 NK               0.0532          0.0585          0.0198
```

Comment: Thank you. However, unlike your output, my output assigns the rowname as a column when I ran your code.

Comment: It does create a column with row names. If you want to return the row names, then you can add `column_to_rownames()` after `group_by()`.

Comment: But `map_dfr(.x = list(EPICdeconv.output, methylcibersort.output, methylresolver.output), ~ .x %>% rownames_to_column()) %>% group_by(rowname) %>% column_to_rownames() %>% summarise(across(everything(), mean)) %>% ungroup()` returns an error that `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`, despite not having any duplicates in the `rowname` column

Comment: Apologies, if you want to keep the row names, then `column_to_rownames()` should be included after `ungroup()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `NA` rows to make all dataframes the same shape, combine into a 3D array, then average along the third dimension using `apply(mean)`:

```r
merge_avg <- function(...) {
  dfs <- list(...)
  # check all columns are numeric
  stopifnot(all(sapply(dfs, sapply, is.numeric)))
  all_rownames <- unique(unlist(lapply(dfs, rownames)))
  dfs <- lapply(dfs, \(df) {
    df[setdiff(all_rownames, rownames(df)), ] <- NA
    as.matrix(df)
  })
  dfs |>
    simplify2array() |>
    apply(c(1, 2), mean, na.rm = TRUE) |>
    as.data.frame()
}

merge_avg(
  methylcibersort.output,
  methylresolver.output,
  EPICdeconv.output
)
```

Output:

```
      TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 TCGA.Y8.A897.01
CD8        0.03167276      0.03026499      0.03492059
Bcell      0.15925482      0.15119051      0.12314944
Macro      0.06281677      0.07067563      0.05987939
NK         0.05320353      0.05850410      0.01975430
```

This assumes columns are the same across dataframes. If that won’t always be the case, you can add `NA` columns using the same approach.